# How to pull values out of a list and put it into a text box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a form for people to enter a username, if the username is taken, it will give them 3 options for alternatives with radio buttons next to them. I'm trying to have an onclick function that will take the corresponding radio button, and put the value of that into the text box. I am using ASP.NET MVC 3. Here is the view I'm working with:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ChangeUsername";
}
<script type="text/javascript">
function setText(target) {
    var txt = document.getElementById(target);
    var temp = txt.value;
    var tf = document.getElementById("uName_change");
    tf.value = temp;
}
</script>
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeUsername", "User", new AjaxOptions() { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "change_name" }, new { uniqueUserId = @Model.UserGuid }))
{   
<div class="form_section">
    <h3>Update Username:
    </h3>
    <div class="form_item">
        <div class="frm_label">
            <label for="username">
                @AdminResource.CurrentUserName
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <p>@Model.UserName</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_item">
        <div class="frm_label">
            <label for="username">
                @AdminResource.UserName
            </label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewUsername, new { id = "uName_change" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewUsername)
            @if (Model.AlternateUsernames != null && Model.AlternateUsernames.Count() != 0)
            {
                    <p>
                        <strong>Suggested usernames:</strong><br />
                        @foreach (var username in Model.AlternateUsernames)
                        {
                            <input type="radio" name="un" id="un_Change" value="@username" onclick="setText(target);" />@username<br />
                        }
                    </p>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_item">
        <div class="frm_label">
            <label for="password">
                &nbsp;</label>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update Username" class="btn_primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserGuid)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.UserName)

}
```

Everything works as it should, except for the javascript part to append the value of the alternatives to the text field. What am I doing wrong on the javascript? Or is it the fact that the "AlternateUsernames" is a list item?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly,

pass `this` to the function to identify the selected radio as follows

```
<input type="radio" name="un" id="un_Change" value="@username" onclick="setText(this);" />@username<br />
```

And modify the function

```
function setText(radio) {
var txt = document.getElementById('target'); // where target is the id of the text field in which you want to display the selected option
txt.value= radio.value;
}
```

*side note: you've set `id` for radio buttons inside a loop which makes your HTML invalid..*

Comment: when i try it this way i get a "unable to set property 'value' of undefined or null reference" error in the javascript. does it make a difference that these "alternatenames" are coming from a "List" item in the viewmodel?

Comment: That is because there is no text field with id `target` replace it with the id of your text field in which you want to display the selected option..

Comment: tried this: ('uName_change'); and this ('#uName_change') and this ("uName_change"); and this ("#uName_change"); still all the same error. it errors out on the "txt.value = radio.value" line.

Comment: In the question you've mentioned that you want to display the selected option in a text box. what is the id of the text box..? why are you playing with the id of radio buttons instead..?!! are you sure you explained the question properly..?

Comment: the id of the textbox is "uName_change"!

Comment: well i can't find a text field with that name in your code... it's null because there is no such  textbox..